# driving distance using google distance matrix

Tags: api, matrix

according to this google article https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/
i am trying to find out a driving distance between two locations or more ,

so i have initially two post codes   which are   M145AR (mancester) and NE65HL (Newcastle upon type)

here is my post url

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=M145AR&destination=NE65HL&sensor=false&mode=driving

when i look a the xml response that i receive for this ,  i can't find out any way of getting the driving distance  between  my manchester post to Newcastle upon tyne post code

could some one let me know whats wrong with my post url ?

see bellow code i use for this

string strURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=53.452824,-2.220085&destination=54.981049,-1.580597&mode=driving&sensor=false";
                List distances = new List();

```
            distances.Clear();
            HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);

            HttpWebResponse wResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse();
            if (wRequest.HaveResponse)
            {
                if (wResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    StreamReader StreamHandler = new System.IO.StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream());
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.LoadXml(StreamHandler.ReadToEnd());
                    Response.Write(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance").Count.ToString() + ",");
                    for (int w = 0; w < xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance").Count; w++)
                    {
                        distances.Add(float.Parse(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance")[w].ChildNodes[0].InnerText));                            
                    }
                }

                string aa = string.Empty;
            }
```

when i check the   distances     list  i get bellow arrays
Count = 27

```
[0]: 106.0
[1]: 53.0
[2]: 457.0
[3]: 2470.0
[4]: 2106.0
[5]: 805.0
[6]: 1211.0
[7]: 6349.0
[8]: 660.0
[9]: 1226.0
[10]: 59693.0
[11]: 19597.0
[12]: 60784.0
[13]: 16839.0
[14]: 54486.0
[15]: 890.0
[16]: 475.0
[17]: 5702.0
[18]: 1388.0
[19]: 406.0
[20]: 161.0
[21]: 1405.0
[22]: 605.0
[23]: 489.0
[24]: 34.0
[25]: 72.0
[26]: 238469.0
```

so i don't know which is the real driving distance from manchester to newcastle . 
according to google the rough estimation for  driving distance between manchester and newcastle is :  148   miles

i am not sure how i get this value out of the google xml response, 
any help will be appreciated .

regards
kksfdo

Comment: any one has any comments on my issue above ?

Comment: http://www.chriswood.ca/blog/2012/03/google-maps-distance-api-csharp-net/

Comment: chris wood has posted an example code to demonstrate how to get this work ,   hope this help some one else in the community

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate only the driving distance but not distance for each step while you drive then you can simply opt for using the distance matrix.

If you change your URL
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=53.452824,-2.220085&destination=54.981049,-1.580597&mode=driving&sensor=false

to the URL http://maps.google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origin=53.452824,-2.220085&destination=54.981049,-1.580597&mode=driving&sensor=false

you will get the distance and duration of the total trip but not the distance for each step in driving to the destination.

It is a pretty old question but as it is unanswered I tried to help out. Any suggestions are appreciated.